# how do I save the cursor position when replacing textarea with a regular expression?

Tags: reactjs

how do I save the cursor position when replacing textarea with a regular expression? Now when typing, if there are 2(two) in the text, it is replaced by 3 and the cursor jumps to the end, if there is no 2, it does not jump.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-haze-rb7kp

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setText(text.replace("2", "3"));
  }, [text]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <textarea value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <br />
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab selectionStart from event and use setSelectionRange to set cursor

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <textarea
        value={text}
        onChange={e => {
          let target = e.target;
          let val = target.value;
          const cursor = e.target.selectionStart;
          val = val.includes("2") ? val.replace("2", "3") : val;
          setText(val);
          setTimeout(() => {
            target.setSelectionRange(cursor, cursor);
          }, 10);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}
```